# Create a copy of a module instead of an instance in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, module, instance

this would be my first question ever on stackoverflow, hope this goes well.
I've been working on a game (using corona SDK) and I used Node.js to write a small little server to handle some chat messages between my clients, no problems there.
Now I'm working on expanding this little server to do some more, and what I was thinking to do is create an external file (module) that will hold an object that has all the functions and variables I would need to represent a Room in my games "Lobby", where 2 people can go into to play one against the other, and each time I have 2 players ready to play, I would create a copy of this empty room for them, and then initialize the game in that room.
So I have an array in my main project file, where each cell is a room, and my plan was to import my module into that array, and then I can init the game in that specific "room", the players would play, the game will go on, and all would be well... but... my code in main.js:

```
var new_game_obj = require('./room.js');

games[room_id] = new_game_obj();

games[room_id].users = [user1_name,user2_name];
```

Now, in my room.js, I have something of the sort:

```
var game_logistics = {};

game_logistics.users = new Array();

game_logistics.return_users_count = function(){
    return game_logistics.users.length;
}

module.exports = function() {
    return game_logistics;
}
```

So far so good, and this work just fine, I can simply go:

```
games[room_id].return_users_count()
```

And I will get 0, or 1, or 2, depending of course how many users have joined this room.
The problems starts once I open a new room, since Node.js will instance the module I've created and not make a copy of it, if I now create a new room, even if I eliminated and/or deleted the old room, it will have all information from the old room which I've already updated, and not a new clean room. Example:

```
var new_game_obj = require('./room.js');

games["room_1"] = new_game_obj();
games["room_2"] = new_game_obj();

games["room_1"].users = ["yuval","lahav"];

_log(games["room_1"].return_user_count()); //outputs 2...
_log(games["room_2"].return_user_count()); //outputs 2...
```

Even doing this:

```
var new_game_obj = require('./room.js');
games["room_1"] = new_game_obj();

var new_game_obj2 = require('./room.js');
games["room_2"] = new_game_obj2();

games["room_1"].users = ["yuval","lahav"];

_log(games["room_1"].return_user_count()); //outputs 2...
_log(games["room_2"].return_user_count()); //outputs 2...
```

Gives the same result, it is all the same instance of the same module in all the "copies" I make of it.
So my question as simple as that, how do I create a "clean" copy of my original module instead of just instancing it over and over again and actually have just one messy room in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is this (replacing your `require()` call with what gets returned);

```
var new_game_obj = function() {
    return game_logistics;
}
```

So, every time you call `new_game_obj`, you return the *same* instance of `game_logistics`.

Instead, you need to make `new_game_obj` return a *new* instance of `game_logistics`;

```
// room.js
function Game_Logistics() {
    this.users = [];

    this.return_users_count = function(){
        return this.users.length;
    };
}

module.exports = function() {
    return new Game_Logistics(); 
}
```

This is quite a shift in mentality. You'll see that we're using `new` on `Game_Logistics` in `module.exports` to return a *new* instance of `Game_Logistics` each time it's called.

You'll also see that inside `Game_Logistics`, `this` is being used everywhere rather than `Game_Logistics`; this is to make sure we're referencing the correct *instance* of `Game_Logistics` rather than the constructor function.

I've also capitalized your `game_logistics` function to adhere to the widely-followed naming convention that constructor functions should be capitalized ([more info](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)).

Taking advantage of the prototype chain in JavaScript is recommended when you're working with multiple instances of functions. You can peruse various articles on "javascript prototypical inheritance* (e.g. [this one](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain.html)), but for now, the above will accomplish what you need.

Comment: Yep, learn how to properly use the `new` keyword and write "proper" javascript classes rather than object literals.  Check out [this article on javascript classes](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) for some good discussion on the options available to you and what makes them different.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this seems to work, I'm sorry my javascript is not "proper" enough, I'm from actionscript/lua/php background, and although I used to dab in javascript, html and xml in past, I was never an "expert", but I learn as I go with the help of some good people, thanks for the links, I will read those ASAP! :)

Comment: @Yuval: No need to apologize, everyone was "new" once :).

Comment: @Jason thanks for the link to the article, it was very informative, short and to the point, and gave me just the information I was missing.

Comment: Yep, it helped me out too, when I was learning this stuff.  I started out writing my objects as literals, just like you did in your original code, I didn't fully understand how to use the prototyping strategy or why I would ever write something complex enough in javascript to require it (before I started with node).  There's reasons to use both methods, but it's become clearer to me over time that the prototyping strategy was more useful more of the time.